# how to create an IPA file having the UDID of the device and not the actual device

Tags: ios5, ipa, udid, archiving

I have the capability of archiving and getting an IPA file if i have the device connected to the Mac. But now i need to create an IPA file and send it over seas...I have the device's UDID how can i accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the device UDID in the [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/devices/index.action). After you do that, you need to recreate your AdHoc Provisioning Profile and add it to Xcode.